# Google provider in Thunderbid with Lightning is not working

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, calendar, google-calendar, lightning

Ever since Thunderbird+Lightning offers immediate bilinear contact with Google Calendar, I have been using it. But there seems to be a problem in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation: Google provider is not working. In fact, Lightning is not allowing me to connect to my Google Calendar account whatsoever!

So when trying to configure my Google calendars, I first try to add a network calendar, then I pick Google:

[image]

At this stage I would hope for the "location" input to disappear so that I could use an open session. This is how it works in my other Thunderbird settings (in a Fedora and Mac I have at work) and is how I wanted it to work in the first place. But as it is not working, I then proceed to input my email address, but alas:

[image]

As you can see it does not accept it, and so I cannot use the Lightning extension.

I'm running:

⠀Thunderbird 31.40
⠀Lightning 3.3.4
⠀Google provider 0.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use *Lightining* and *Provider for Google Calendar* addons from Ubuntu repositories or from Thunderbird addons repository on https://addons.mozilla.org/it/thunderbird/?

Try to remove both packages from Ubuntu repositories and install both *Lightning* and *Provider fo Google Calendar* from https://addons.mozilla.org/it/thunderbird/ and try again.

Recently authentication model for Google Calendar has changed, and you need updated addons to make it work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked as intended! I was indeed using the repository packages and, namely, the provider was WAY outdated.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Calendar in location box you have to paste a XML private URL to your calendar.
Go to http://google.com/calendar, click down arrow on the right of your calendar name and open calendar settings. Now copy private XML calendar URL and paste it in location box in Lightning